# How to use a function pointer to a static member function as a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

This code

```
template <void (*func)()>
static void call() { func(); }

template <typename T>
struct A {
    A() { call<static_func>(); }   // <--- error
    static void static_func() {}
};

A<int> a;

int main() {}
```

results in the following error message (gcc 4.4.5):

```
test.cc:6: error: 'static void A<T>::static_func() [with T = int]'
                   cannot appear in a constant-expression
```

The error disappears after doing either of the following:

1. Qualify the template parameter of `call` with `A::` or `A<T>::`, i.e. use `call<A::static_func>()` instead of `call<static_func>()`.
2. Remove the template parameter of `A`, i.e. make `A` a non-template class.
3. Make `static_func()` a global function (with external linkage).

Why is the above code wrong?  And why do the mentioned fixes work?  Especially 1 and 2 seem very strange to me.  Judging from the error message, the extra qualification doesn't seem to provide any information the compiler doesn't know anyway.

Comment: The first alternative is the right one I would say.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: That's of course what I'm using for now.  I'd just like to understand what's going on here.

Comment: It sounds like it could have something to do with the compiler's implementation of two phase lookup or something.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Actually this is a limitation of your compiler. Your code should work just fine.

Comment: Gonna second @FailedDev, the compiler *obviously* knows the exact function, as evident from the error message, so spelling it out `call<A::static_func>` should change nothing.

Comment: FWIW, gcc 4.6.1 also says that the error happens "In constructor 'A<T>::A() [with T = int]'". Isn't this to be expected; without scope resolution `A::static_func()` isn't visible at the time of instantiation of `A`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [bug in GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35167).

Comment: Thanks.  It's reassuring that at least once the compiler is wrong, not me. :)